# C# - Making a program with variables when called?

Tags: c#, variables, batch-file

I honestly have no idea how to find what I want to know but I will do my best to explain what I would like to know.

There are programs like cmdmenusel.exe which can be called in languages like batch. But when calling it in batch, it requires other variables, like so: Syntax - cmdmenusel.exe {color} {Option 1} {Option 2} etc..

I would like to know how to make a program like this, that accepts and understands variables outside the file when it is called. My plan is to make a mailer program, that accepts the variables like, for example:

mailer.exe -subject "This is a subject" -body "This is the body paragraph." -mailto "somewhere@somewhere.com"

Preferably in C# I would like to able to do this. Thanks.

Thanks in Advance.

- Right

Comment: I guess you are looking for Command Line Argument.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa288457(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/main

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by just creating a basic console application and passing the values in as arguments.  By default, the Main method with accepts an array of arguments for you to reference.